# Group by MySQL Date field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, group-by, grouping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listing diary events grouped by days in PHP/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040695/listing-diary-events-grouped-by-days-in-php-mysql)

I've got a database which holds live band gigs for my town, each gig is stored as a record in my MySQL database.

I'd like to group by day to see the gigs on my website. But the GROUP BY function will only show 1 record. How can I show all gigs under one date?

My MySQL structure..

```
ID  date                    content
1   2012-12-02 00:00:00     Gig 1
2   2012-12-02 00:00:00     Gig 2
1   2012-12-03 00:00:00     Gig 1
2   2012-12-03 00:00:00     Gig 2
```

I'd like to show like this..

```
-- Sun 02 December 2012 --
Gig 1
Gig 2

-- Mon 03 December 2012 --
Gig 1
Gig 2
```

Comment: Formatting and display should be done in the client, not in SQL.

Comment: I've tried using GROUP BY but it only shows 1 record for each date

Comment: What is the SQL statement that you used?

Comment: You are looking for `order by date ASC`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY(date)`

Comment: I've tried using `order by date ASC` which does display all gigs. But they are not grouped under a heading of the date. If that makes sense?

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY date`, but you'll need to format the output in your client code. Detect a change in the date value to trigger your formatting output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't group the results in the database layer, do it in your presentation layer.  For example, using PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$qry = $dbh->query('
  SELECT   UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date), content
  FROM     gigs
  WHERE    date > NOW()
  ORDER BY date
');

if ($qry->execute()) {

  // output headers
  echo '<h1>Upcoming gigs</h1>';

  $row = $qry->fetch();
  while ($row) {
    $current_date = $row['date'];

    // output $current_date initialisation
    echo '<h2>', date('D d F Y', $current_date), '</h2><ul>';

    do {
      // output $row details
      echo '<li>', htmlentities($row['content']), '</li>';
    } while ($row = $qry->fetch() and $row['date'] == $current_date);

    // output $current_date termination
    echo '</ul>';
  }

  // output footers

}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I'm getting an error with this code though `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name'`

Comment: You may need to alter the [DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) to suit your needs.

Comment: Ah yes I was being stupid. Sorted that now and the script is running but no gig information is coming through. The date is stored as a DATETIME field, will that be ok?

Comment: Yes, it should be.  Is anything being displayed at all?  The header?

Comment: Sorry being an idiot again! Sorted it and it works perfectly. Many thanks!

Comment: Here's the DSN I used in case anyone else needs to know..

`$dsn = 'mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DBNAME';
$username = 'USER';
$password = 'PASS'; 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);`

Comment: @Tom: You shouldn't need `username` and `password` in the DSN.  But the `host` part would be required if it's non-default (default is usually localhost).

Comment: I see, thanks. The only issue I now have is the date being displayed as "Wed 31 December 1969"

Comment: Oh, sorry.  You need to alias `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) AS date` in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   SELECT  * 
   FROM    your_table
   WHERE  date = '".$your_variable_of_selectedDate."'
   GROUP BY date
   ORDER BY date
```

EDIT :
if u dont have date variable then just give a specific date

```
   SELECT  date , content 
   FROM    your_table

   GROUP BY date
   ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "$your_variable_of_selectedDate" bit?

Comment: the date that u will give to show your gigs on date date .  have select options of dates ? if u dont have date variable , just use a date insttead

Comment: I see what you mean. I've entered a date, but it's still showing gigs from the same day separately

Comment: what u mean separatly ? give exemple how?

Comment: It's showing like this..  


   -- Sun 02 December 2012 --  

    Gig 1

   -- Sun 02 December 2012 --
    Gig 2


    -- Mon 03 December 2012 --

    Gig 1

    -- Mon 03 December 2012 --
    Gig 2

Comment: Now it's only show the first record for each date, which I believe is all that GROUP BY is capable of. Thanks for your help