# Display same-year events together (PHP/MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with with some events dated in specific years, like 3 or 4 in the same year. My table is like this:

```
year | event
-----------------
2004 | Event 1
2004 | Event 2
2005 | Event 3
2005 | Event 4
```

And I want to display them like this:

```
2004
- Event 1
- Event 2

2005
- Event 1
- Event 2
```

Any idea? thank you very much!

This is my actual plain query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM expos WHERE activo = 1 ORDER BY anio");
echo "<ul id=\"expos\">";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<li>";
    echo $row['anio']."<br />";
    echo $row['titulo'];
    echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: Show us your SQL query and the PHP code you're currently using. It will be as simple as outputting a heading if it hasn't been output before.

Comment: Sort by year, then by however you want them sorted within a given year.  When looping through the records for display, keep a variable for the "current year" in the loop.  Each time you display a record, check if that record's year matches the variable.  If it doesn't, display a new header for the new year and update the variable.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13040704

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers! I edited my question with the query, I will check that like now.

Comment: I solved the problem but I can't post the answer, I need to wait for 7 hours. Thanks Eggyal, I used your link to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

you are doing your query ok!.

i think that if you can make a new camp adding the day. the query most be easier.

you just have to order it but if you dint have the day you can make this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if($back==$row["anio"] || $back==""){
      $var_array[] = $row["evento"];
    }
    if($back!=$row["anio"]){
      foreach($var_array as &$item){
        $number=explode(" ",$item);
        $number_event[] =$number;
        //this is for getting just the number.
      }
      //bubble sort    both are for ordering the array event!.
      //shell sort

      //here just display with foreach and echo 

      $back = $row["anio"];

    }
}
```

see you!